# What is the effect of "list=list" in Python modules?

Tags: python

I've seen following code in the python standard library `/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py`:

```
list = list
dict = dict
```

What does this idiom mean? My best guess is: "let's check if `dict` and `list` exist".
Is it just legacy code from the ancient times without `list` and `dict` in the `__builtins__`?

And I have another mad guess: *optimization* of lookup speed moving `list` from global scope to module scope. Is it sane assumption regarding the idiom? I see, that the assumption is wrong if I apply it to multiprocessing.

Comment: (+1) for the interesting question. Given that `multiprocessing` was introduced in Python 2.6, it doesn't seem too likely that the code is very old.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I thought that `multiprocessing` was old enough to use it in Python 2.4 as there is no note "Since 2.6" in docs[1] :(
[1] http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I don't think it really matters here, but there is a "New in version 2.6." note on the entire module: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Exports. You then can do:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import list
```

... which happens to be the regular `list`.

Without that line, there would be no `list` in the package `multiprocessing.dummy`.

This is sensible to have a uniform API across packages. Say all packages are supposed to offer a `list` class. Package `a` chooses to provide a custom implementation, package `b` however wants to use the `list` from `__builtins__`.

```
powerful/__init__.py:
from powerfulinternals import PowerfulList as list
from simple.simpleinternals import Something as whoo

simple/__init__.py:
list = list
from simpleinternals import Something as whoo

application.py:
try:
  import powerful as api
else:
  import simple as api

mylist = api.list()
woot = api.whoo()
```

There more reason to do such things. For example to make it explicit what you are using.

```
list = list
```

can also be seen as a statement "if you want to change the type of lists I'm using, change it here."

In this particular case, it is the former. The `list` and `dict` are exposed as:

```
manager = multiprocessing.dummy.Manager()
l = manager.list()
d = manager.dict()
```

And the definition of `Manager` is:

```
def Manager():
  return sys.modules[__name__]
```

i.e. `Manager.list = list`.

Comment: Is this for forwards compatibility or why would anyone need to import a builtin from somewhere else than `__builtin__`? Or is this something specific to do with the way `multiprocessing.dummy` module works?

Comment: It is not restricted to builtins.

Comment: I second Kimvais question. `multiprocessing` does not export `dict` and `list`, so I see no good reason to do that.

Comment: That is the *effect*, but what is the *reason*? I can't think of any reason why it'd be there... can't see any usage of `multiprocessing.dummy.list` or `multiprocessing.dummy.dict`.

Comment: `multiprocessing.dummy` implements the `Manager` interface, which is supposed to have `list` and `dict` methods. Try: `print dir(multiprocessing.dummy.Manager())` (and see my latest edit)

Comment: Arg, I'm certainly not impressed that I didn't observe the `def Manager(): return sys.modules[__name__]` bit. +1.

Comment: As a side-note: this only works at the module level; inside a function you get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment`;  to get around that you would have to `import __builtin__; list = __builtin__.list` (`builtins` in Python 3.x)